# Force to use enter instead of click in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've a problem :

```
 document.querySelector('#target').click();
```

I've this code with the `click()` method, but I would like to click on the target pressing the enter (keycode = 13), of course with javascript not physically. So how is it possible to do?

Here is a js fiddle, for representing how does it look like...

```
 https://jsfiddle.net/
```

Of course, I would like to solve this problem within the developer mode, so running the script in the console.

Please help me to solve this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for downvoting. Instead of clicking on the -1 I would be very pleased if you could say an answer for it, Of course I know you click -1, because you dont know the answer

Comment: Perhaps the downvoter was reacting to your empty link to JSFiddle (there is a reason you could not post it - SO tells you why). Instead of posting code there, post it here. Have a look at the [help] to see how to post better questions

Comment: Oh, :), I see Somehow it disappeard, never mind, thanks for your kindness

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you're using jquery you could use :

```
$('#target').trigger({type: 'keypress',which: character.charCodeAt(13)});
```

Or also :

```
var ev = jQuery.Event("keypress");
ev.which = 13;

$("#target").trigger(ev);
```

Hope this helps.